# How to use a fully variable URL in routerLink param

Tags: angular, routerlink

Let, I have an URL like below (I am actually getting it by get method)-

`/glaccounts/pending_tasks?taskId=2&taskCommand="CreateGeneralLedgerAccount"`

this URL resides on an **object** like this- `{activity:"work", taskUI="/glaccounts/pending_tasks?taskId=2&taskCommand="CreateGeneralLedgerAccount"}`

Now, how to use that in routerLink? The code below is not working-

```
<ul class="weekly-weather">
    <li *ngFor="let task of pendingTasks">
       <a [routerLink]="task.taskUI" [queryParams]="{taskId: '2', taskCommand: 'CreateGeneralLedgerAccount'}">
           {{task.activity}}
       </a>
       <i class="material-icons">call_missed_outgoing</i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**(Note: Here, I am getting an array of objects in pendingTasks)**

I have also tried

- `[routerLink]=[task.taskUI]`
- `[routerLink]=[{{task.taskUI}}]`
- `[routerLink]="{{task.taskUI}}"`
- `[routerLink]={{task.taskUI}}`

Last three throw errors obviously. :P

Comment: Object should be like this `{activity:"work", taskUI:"/glaccounts/pending_tasks"}` .

Comment: It's actually like that :P. It is coming from the service. Edited that

Comment: this should work `[routerLink]="task.taskUI"`, what's the error you get ?

Answer (score 1):

`routerLink` accepts an array of strings or strings.

Make a function that creates an array of strings, then use it

```
toLink(url: string)  {
  const arr = url.split('/');
  if (arr[arr.length - 1] === '') { arr.pop(); } // remove the last empty item
  if (arr[0] === '') { arr.shift(); } // remove the first empty item
  return arr;
}



<a [routerLink]="toLink(task.taskUI)">
```

Also remember, this will work if you want to go down in the URL tree. This means that this route must be a child of the route you're on.

Comment: Additionally, you'll want to split and parametrize those query parameters.

Comment: What's the point of splitting the params if the function handles that already ? And I think he already did the routes, but in the case that he didn't, I imagine it won't take long to notice it.

Comment: I'm talking about query params. Note his example url: `/glaccounts/pending_tasks?taskId=2&taskCommand="CreateGeneralLedgerAccount"`.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't had this URL when I commented !